# How many matrices are possible for the given arrangement?

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, nt.number-theory

Given m & n, we have to find out the number of possible matrices of order m*n with the property that A(i,j) can be either 0 or 1 and that no contiguous sub-matrix of both length > 1 & breadth > 1 should have same entries i.e. all of its cells shouldn't be 0 or 1. For example if m = 2 & n = 2, the answer is 14: Total possibilities : 2 ^ (2 * 2); Invalid cases: when all 4 cells are 0 or 1. Therefore answer is 2 ^ (2 * 2) - 2 = 14. A sub-matrix of length > 1 & breadth = 1, also breadth > 1 & length = 1 is valid.

Comment: It suffices that your matrix avoids $2 \times 2$-submatrices with all entries equal, since if you have a forbidden $3\times 3$-matrix or larger, it will automatically also contain a forbidden $2 \times 2$-matrix. Is it possible to count these using recursion maybe?

Comment: @Per Alexandersson: It is evident that we'll have (m - 1) * (n - 1) sub-matrices of order 2 * 2. My strategy is: start picking up 2 * 2 sub-matrices starting from top-left corner i.e. containing cells A(0,0), A(0,1), A(1,0), A(1,1) of main matrix; fill it with 0 and count the total number of matrices having these cells filled in this manner. Now, I proceed on to counting those matrices where the next 2 * 2 matrix i.e. A(0,1), A(0,2), A(1,1), A(1,2) are filled with 0. However, I am not able to count the repeating cases of 2nd matrix which already appeared in the first case. How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you clarify the term "contiguous sub-matrix"? 


Comment: @Pietro Majer: Contiguous means that the rows and columns of the chosen sub-matrix should be adjascent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of $2 \times n$ -matrices avoiding constant 2*2-submatrices.
Then

$$a_n = \frac{2^{-n} \left(4 \left(17+4 \sqrt{17}\right)
   \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right)^n+\left(\sqrt{17}-17\right)
   \left(\sqrt{17}-3\right)^n e^{i \pi  n}\right)}{17
   \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right)}$$

This should be fairly straightforward to prove,
let $v(n)=(e_{01}(n),e_{10}(n),e_{00}(n),e_{11}(n))$ be the vector of number of $2\times n$-matrices ending with column 01, 10, 00 resp. 11.

We then have the recursion
$$v(n+1)=\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} v(n)$$

Since this is symmetric, we may diagonalize this and from here, it should be straightforward to find the formula above.
(I cheated a bit in Mathematica).

EDIT: Of course, $e_{01}(n)=e_{10}(n)$ and $e_{00}(n)=e_{11}(n)$ by symmetry,
so one can of course reduce the above to a 2 by 2 matrix recursion instead, with entries 2,2 and 2,1. Eigenvalues of this matrix are $1/2 (3 + \sqrt{17}), 1/2 (3 - \sqrt{17})$
which explains the strange formula above.

Comment: How does m fit in this formula?

Comment: This can be generalized to $m \times n$ matrices with fixed $m$, using a $2^m \times 2^m$ matrix with rows and columns indexed by the members of $\{0,1\}^m$.  For example, the matrix in the $m=3$ case is
$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccccccc} 0&0&1&1&0&1&1&1\\ 0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1
\\1&1&1&0&1&1&1&0\\ 0&1&1&1&0&1&1
&1\\ 1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\ 1&1&1&1&1&1
&0&0\\ 1&1&1&0&1&1&0&0\end {array} \right]$$

Comment: If my Maple calculations are correct, the result in the case $m=3$ is then $$\sum_r \frac{17 + 9 r - 6 r^2}{15 r^n}$$
where the sum is over the roots of the polynomial $2 z^3 - 3 z^2 - 6 z + 1$.

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A133129

Comment: @Robert Israel: m's max value can be 6 and n's max value can be 2^63. Can you tell me how are you able to deduce the matrix based on m's value. Is it some algorithmic technique or just by observing it. Also, can there be derived any recursive relation? 

Comment: Given that I know the value for m * m matrix. Can this value help me in finding the answer for m * (m + 1), m * (m + 2), ... matrices?

Comment: I wonder if the sequence of characteristic polynomials obtained from these matrices have nice properties. They're certainly real-rooted, I wonder maybe if they can be found recursively in a nice manner...

Comment: The $2^m \times 2^m$ matrix $A$ for the recursion is obtained as follows: $A_{ij} = 0$ if for some $k$, $1 \le k \le m$, the $k$'th and $k+1$'th binary digits of $i-1$ and $j-1$ (allowing leading $0$'s) are all equal, otherwise $A_{ij} = 0$.  Thus in the case $m=3$ I had $A_{84} = 0$ because $7 = (111)_2$ and $3 = (011)_2$.
Then $a_n = (1,\ldots,1) M^{n-1} (1,\ldots,1)^T$. 

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A181245 .  This is stated as "no 2X2 circuit having pattern 0101 in any orientation", but that's equivalent if you switch $0$'s and $1$'s in a checkerboard pattern.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :
I've edited the argument to make it stronger
Suppose that $m\geq 3$ and $n\geq 5$ so that there is a 3x5 submatrix A. I show that the number of possibilities is zero in this case.

In A, there are at least two rows with at least there $1$'s each (up to relabeling the symbols). Since we cannot have a constant 2x2 submatrix, we may assume that the first two rows of the matrix are 
[11100] and
[00111].

To avoid a 2x2 contant submatrix, the first two entries of the third row must be different, but then, whatever choice we make for the third one, we will get a constant 2x2-submatrix in the first and third row.

The answer for $m=1$ and $m=2$ is not hard to calculate explicitly.

Together with the answer above, this reduces the problem to checking the following cases (which is not too hard):
3x3,3x4,4x4.

Comment: What about the case when m = 5 & n = 5 and the matrix is: 
0 1 0 1 0 | 0 1 0 1 0 | 0 1 0 1 0 | 0 1 0 1 0 | 0 0 1 1 0 The above is a valid case.

Comment: I assumed that you meant any sub-matrix, but now I see that you meant only submatrices consisting of adjacent rows and columns. Maybe you should clarify your question.

Comment: This is kind of irrelevant now that we know OP meant avoiding constant submatrices of adjacent rows and columns, but you can get a $3 \times 5$ matrix A avoiding constant $2 \times 2$ (general) submatrices by choosing $(1,0,0,0,1)$ as the third row; this choice is ok because your argument doesn't require the third row to have three $1$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [this](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/3706/cbars-editorial) could help.